# Relational schema and integrity constraints?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

May I ask if you can use constraint to set limited so that one member (clen) can play for just one club (klub) ? My point is that this does not happen, for example: id_member = 1 && id_club = 1; ...., id_member = 1 && id_club = 2;
What I have does not seem entirely appropriate to me here and it occurs to me that it does not solve this problem.

```
ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT unq_member_and_club UNIQUE(id_member, id_club);
```

Is it possible to solve this with integrity constraints in the create script at all or are triggers used for it? I am a part of my create script.

**Schema**

[image]

**Create script**

```
CREATE TABLE club (
id_club SERIAL NOT NULL,
nazev VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
datum_zalozeni VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE club ADD CONSTRAINT pk_club PRIMARY KEY (id_club);
ALTER TABLE club ADD CONSTRAINT uc_club_nazev UNIQUE (nazev);

CREATE TABLE coach (
    id_member INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE coach ADD CONSTRAINT pk_coach PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

CREATE TABLE member (
    id_member SERIAL NOT NULL,
    id_club INTEGER NOT NULL,
    jmeno VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    prijmeni VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    narodnost VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    datum_narozeni VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT pk_member PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

CREATE TABLE owner (
    id_member INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE owner ADD CONSTRAINT pk_owner PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

CREATE TABLE player (
    id_member INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cislo VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    post VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE player ADD CONSTRAINT pk_player PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

ALTER TABLE coach ADD CONSTRAINT fk_coach_member FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES member (id_member) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT fk_member_club FOREIGN KEY (id_club) REFERENCES club (id_club) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE owner ADD CONSTRAINT fk_owner_member FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES member (id_member) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE player ADD CONSTRAINT fk_player_member FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES member (id_member) ON DELETE CASCADE;
enter code here
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need:

```
ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT unq_member_and_club UNIQUE(id_member, id_club);
```

because `id_member` is PK of `member` then there is only one record with `id_member = 1` then it is not posible to have `id_club = 1 and = 2` simultaneously for `id_member = 1`. Thats ocurs for any `id_member`.